# Making a mySQL-query to get products that have not ben sold?

Tags: mysql, openbravo

Using openbravoPOS i got a mySQL database of all my producs tickets stock etc.

Products are in one table and the tickets are in another, so to make a query that get me all the products that are sold (and therefore are in ticketlines) are simple.

How do I make a query that gives me the products that are not i any ticketlines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`LEFT OUTER JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) for this:

```
select p.*
from products p
left outer join tickets t on p.ProductID = t.ProductID
where t.ProductID is null
```